# Facebook page content only for fans

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like, fbml, facebook-page

I'm looking for a way to limit some of the content of the fan page from the users that are not fans.

On my page I have a tab application that just shows an iframe of a webpage on my server(Non-PHP server). Inside the page I have coupon code that is displayed for the fans of the page.

Unfortunately, non-fans can come in and grab the code without liking the page.

I have tried  but not only it doesnt work, it also is depreciated and will no longer work from June 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check http://apps.facebook.com/iframehost/

Comment: I just checked it out and its great! Just what I needed. Ofcourse, I would like to have full control of the app tab, but having fan and non-fan is good enough. 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

When a user first lands on your tab for a Facebook page, Facebook passes whether the user is an admin and if the have liked the page in the signed request. Just check what Facebook already passes you. Using something like iframehost means you don't have access to all of Facebook insights reporting, since it's associate with their app, not yours.

```
$parsed_signed_data = $fb->getSignedRequest();
if ( $parsed_signed_data['page']['liked'] ) {
    // They Like us!
} else {
    // They don't like us yet
}
```